# How to modify the text style under the icon in the Android system

Tags: android, ios

How to modify the text style under the icon in the Android system, as shown in the figure below, modify the style and background color of `百亿补贴`, can I use a picture to replace appName alive?

[image]

Hope someone tried it and can help me solve the problem, thank you very much

Comment: If you mean the launcher Icon text then i don't think you can modify it .. Its the launcher APP which take care of this stuff. AFAIK You can not do anything about it ..

Comment: Hope someone tried it and can help me solve the problem, thank you very much